# Referencing relation's relations in Django Serializer

Tags: python, django, ember.js, django-rest-framework, json-api

Let's say I have some models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...

class B(models.Model):
    my_reference_to_a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b_field_1 = ...
    b_field_2 = ...

class C(models.Model):
    my_reference_to_b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    c_field_1 = ...
    ...
```

In my serializer for `C`, I want to include all of the fields in `C`, all the fields in `B`, as well as the reference to `A` in `B` (but not the reference to `B` in `C`), so the JSON API output would be something like this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "type": "C",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "b_field_1": "...",
            "b_field_2": "...",
            "c_field_1": "..."
        },
        "relationships": {
            "a": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "A",
                    "id": "1"
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    ...
}
```

How would I go about this? I've already tried doing something like this inside my serializer for `C`:

```
A = ASerializer(source='my_reference_to_b.my_reference_to_a')
```

But that doesn't work, as DRF doesn't seem to support dotted paths for sources. I've also tried supplying a method that returns the proper model (the model is valid inside the method) as the source, but that outputs the reference in the JSON as:

```
"a": {
    "data": null
}
```

On my `A` model, I also have a reference to another model, `D`, that is not explicitly stated in `A`, but is instead defined in `D` as a OneToMany relationship (Many `D` models to one `A` model) with a resource_name on the ForeignKey declared in `D`, and trying to reference this in `C` to include that relationship in the JSON doesn't work, either. I get this error (trying to reference it by doing `D = DSerializer(source='B.D')`):

```
'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'B'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DRF does support dotted notation. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source . Maybe something is wrong with your ASerializer class. For reverse one-to-one relations, you can use SerializerMethodField with `hasattr` check.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I've had a similar scenario work before, but in that case it was a field referencing a field inside the relation, not a relation inside the relation. That seems to be making the difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just answering my own question in case anyone lands on this page and they need help.

You need to use the `SerializerMethodResourceRelatedField` from the Django Rest Framework JSON API. I had tried the regular `ResourceRelatedField` without it working, looking through the source code showed me that `ResourceRelatedField` doesn't support dotted paths. Instead, use `SerializerMethodResourceRelatedField` with a source pointing to a method that returns the desired relation.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Model
from django.db import models


class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)

# View

from rest_framework import generics,viewsets

from api.models import Album
from api.serializers import AlbumSerializer





class TracksView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

class TracksView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Album.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AlbumSerializer

# serializers
from rest_framework import serializers
from api.models import Album



class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].